# Continuous inclusion map of linear subspaces of space of sequences that converge to zero ($c_0$)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $c_0=\lbrace x=x_1,x_2,...): Lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=0 \rbrace$ be the space of sequences that converge to zero. As we know that $c_0$ is a banach space when it is supplied with supremum norm. If $1\leq p < \infty$ then $l^p$ can be viewed as linear subspaces of $c_0$. Show that the inclusion map from $l^p$ into $c_0$ is continuous.

I try to show that the inclusion map is bounded but I got stuck to reach the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_n) \in l^p$. Then

$|x_n|=(|x_n|^p)^{1/p} \le (\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|^p)^{1/p}=||x||_p$  for all $n$.

Therefore

$||x||_{\infty}=\sup\{|x_n|: n \in \mathbb N\} \le ||x||_p$.

Hence, if $f$ is the inclusion map, then

$||f(x)||_{\infty}=||x||_{\infty}\le ||x||_p$.